# Duclicate Woocommerce Buy Button but only in chrome

Tags: woocommerce

This code is the wrpapper broken only in chrome

Comprar

here is the site...https://automarcasmoto.com.br/categoria-produto/baterias/bateria-route/

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the Stripe plugin's "Payment Request Buttons" feature which integrates with Apple Pay/Chrome Payment Request API

Go to: Payments > Stripe

Then untick "Payment Request Buttons"